# Ada - Task termination error - "Statement expected"

Tags: task, ada

I have the following task

```
   task body auto is
   begin
      Put_Line( licencepalte.all & " set off.");
      delay traveltime.all;
      Put_Line( licencepalte.all & " arrived.");
      loop
         select
            indicator.passthrough;
            terminate; -- error for this line: 'statement expected'
         or 
            delay 0.2;
            Put_Line( licencepalte.all & " is waiting.");
         end select;
      end loop;
   end auto;
```

where we represent an indicator light and some cars (auto ~ automobiles) with tasks and protecteds. My main issue is, that I don't know, how to terminate, in case the indicator accepts the entry of the auto. You can see what I'm currently trying to do, and it pops up an error (see inline). How do I stop the task once the entry gets accepted? Why does this `terminate` not work? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, an `exit` would do nicely instead of `terminate`.

Comment: You're right. Do you know when and how to use terminate? And what kind of statement does it want in this case?

Comment: The syntax at [ARM 9.7.1](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-9-7-1.html) says that you can’t put a statement (`indicator.passthrough;`) between `or` and `terminate`. It can only be `or terminate;`.

Answer (score 4):

`terminate` is not an "action" that you perform.  That is, you can't use a `terminate` statement anywhere you choose in the task body to terminate the task.  The way to terminate a task is for the execution to reach the `end` that ends the body; in your case, `exit` to exit the loop works, as in Jacob's answer.

The purpose of `or terminate` is tell the program that a task is eligible for termination (I don't know if there's a better technical term for this).  Suppose your task looks like:

```
task body Task_Type_1 is 
begin
    loop
        select
            accept Entry_1(...parameters...) do
                -- something
            end Entry_1;
        or
            accept Entry_2(...parameters...) do
                -- something
            end Entry_2;
        end select;
    end loop;
end Task_Type_1;
```

If the "something" code of the `accept` statements never exits the loop, the task will never terminate.  This means that other constructs enclosing the task can never terminate.  For example:

```
procedure Proc is
    T1 : Task_Type_1;
begin
    -- do some stuff
    -- now we're at the end, and we have to wait for T1 to complete
end Proc;
```

The procedure creates a task of type `Task_Type_1` and starts it.  Then the body of the procedure is executed.  When `end Proc;` is reached, the procedure doesn't terminate immediately, because it has to wait until the task finishes its job.  But the way the task is written, the task will never complete.  Therefore `Proc` will never return, and the program will probably deadlock.

`or terminate` is how to say that the task could terminate:

```
task body Task_Type_1 is 
begin
    loop
        select
            accept Entry_1(...parameters...) do
                -- something
            end Entry_1;
        or
            accept Entry_2(...parameters...) do
                -- something
            end Entry_2;
        or 
            terminate;
        end select;
    end loop;
end Task_Type_1;
```

In this small example, where we have a procedure that just creates this one task, `or terminate` means: **if** this task reaches a point where it's blocked in the `select` because there aren't any entry calls waiting, **and** if `Proc` has reached the end of its code, **then** we terminate the task.  The task body exits, any finalization that needs to be done is done, and then `Proc` can complete.

`or terminate` can be used only in a "selective accept".  If you say `select Some_Other_Task.Entry_2(...);` so that it blocks until the other task's entry is available, you can't use `or terminate` in that kind of `select`.

In a more complex case, a procedure could create two or more tasks.  When that procedure reaches its `end` statement, it won't return until (roughly speaking) all the tasks it creates are completed **or** all of the tasks that haven't completed are blocked on `select` statements that have `or terminate` clauses.  If the latter happens, then all of those tasks complete and then the procedure can return.

The rule about "terminate alternatives" is in [RM 9.3(6)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-3.html).  It speaks in terms of depending on a master; in the example I showed above, `Proc` is the master.